# Why the autofocus isn't working in ReactJS with antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm having trouble with the autoFocus, I searched a lot, but none solutions that I found worked for me, I'm using a Drawer with a form inside, that form has some Form.Item with Input, and when I open the drawer, I want to focus on form.item, anybody can help me?

Here is my code:

```
<Drawer>
  <Form layout="vertical" ref={this.formRef} onFinish={this.onFinish} onFinishFailed={this.onFinishFailed}>    
    <Row gutter={16}>
      <Col span={24}>
        <Form.Item
          name="description"
          label="Description"
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: 'Please enter a description.',
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input.TextArea autoFocus rows={10} placeholder="Please enter a description." />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
    </Row>
    <Row style={{ bottom: '0', position: 'absolute', right: '38px' }}>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button
          onClick={this.onClose}
          style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
        >
          Cancel
      </Button>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Row>
  </Form>
</Drawer>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://ant.design/components/input/#Input.TextArea), `autoFocus` is not supported prop (like it is on `<input />` element). Haven't used this ui lib before, so can't say if setting focus manually by using `ref` would work.

UPDATE:

Just have played a bit and it looks like that focus can be set manually:

1. [demo](https://b8l6s.csb.app/)
2. [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-swirles-b8l6s)

Another update:

3. [demo with drawer](https://dbphu.csb.app/)
4. [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-frost-dbphu)

Comment: According to [Drawer Api](https://ant.design/components/drawer/) you can hook into `afterVisibleChange` prop and pass collback which will set focus on element with `ref`

Comment: Cool. Can you upvote my answer and mark it as answered?

Comment: I already upvote your answer, but I don't have 15 point of reputation yet, so my vote didn't count yet, sorry :/

Comment: No problem. Maybe some other time. Btw, I've upvoted your q so you need just 4 more points to earn. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";

const Form = () => {
  const emailInput = useCallback((inputElement) => {
    if (inputElement) {
      inputElement.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        Email
        <input name="email" type="email" ref={emailInput} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password
        <input name="email" type="email" />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

Comment: If you need to focus your field everytime it's shown, not just mounted, see my update below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77289087/358532

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
<Input ref={el => {setTimeout(() => el?.focus(), 0);}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const inputTagRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (inputTagRef.current) {
      inputTagRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [inputTagRef.current]);

 <Input
   ref={inputTagRef}
  />
```

This will add autoFocus to you input field using **antd** ui lib.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update to @manish-baral's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75664611/358532) when you need to focus a field every time it's shown, not just on the first mount (for example, when opening a filter (`filterDropdown`) in an Ant Table):

```
  const filterInput = React.useCallback(
    inputElement => {
      if (inputElement && visible) {
        setTimeout(() => inputElement.focus(), 0);
      }
    },
    [visible]
  );
  // ...
  <Input
    ref={filterInput}
    // ...
  />
```

You need to react to ant's `visible` prop, and to add a `setTimeout` of `0` to wait until the DOM node is truly ready.